# if there are 3 classes A,B,C a and b are in same package c is in different package, to access fields of A why C must be child of A but not b?

Tags: java, inheritance, package

There are **class A , class B, Class C.**

if class A and B are in same package but not C; 
to Access fields of Class A ;  C must be the Child of A.this rule is not for Class B it may or may not be the child of A to access the fields .WHY?

Comment: show us your SAMPLE CODE ?

Comment: If you're talking about `protected` fields, then that's the rule because... that's the rule. `protected` in Java means "accessible by classes in the same package or child classes."

Answer (score 0):

Declare the fields of `class A` and `class B` as `public`. The default visibility when you don't put `public`, `private` etc. is for the fields to be visible only to classes within the same package.

From java docs:

> If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as
>   package-private), it is visible only within its own package (packages
>   are named groups of related classes — you will learn about them in a
>   later lesson.)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html